# Trying load json output into Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I have created a simple mobile app that searches the Best Buy Store API when a user enters a zip code and distance. The app works fine, however I would like to load my json output into Google Maps, preferably with makers or if its easier into a individual map via a hyperlink.

Here is my first page of code that captures the user input on a HTML page:

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="todolist.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prowebapps.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sprintf.js"></script>




<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var cookieName = "smartHomePage";
    var url = "SmarthomePage2.html?";

    /**
        store cookie, then redirect to page2
    **/
    function goto(){
        storeCookies();
        var zip = $("#zipcode").val();
        var miles = $("#milesdistance").val();
        url = url + "zip=" + zip + "&miles=" + miles;
        url += "&placeholder=";
        window.location = url;
    }

    function printCookies(){
        var cookieValue = getCookie(cookieName);
        if(cookieValue == "")
            alert("I have nothing!");
        else
            alert(cookieValue);
    }

    function storeCookies(){
        var zip = $("#zipcode").val();
        var miles = $("#milesdistance").val();
        var cookieValue = "zip=" + zip + "&miles=" + miles;
        setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue);
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) 
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }//getCookie

    function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }//setCookie
</script>


</head>

<h1>SmartHomes Store Locator</h1>


<ul>
    <li><input type="text" name="zip[zipcode]" id="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code"/></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="miles[distance]" id="milesdistance" placeholder="Distance In Miles" /></li>
    <li class="naked">
        <button onclick="goto();">Search</button>
    </li>

    <!--
    <button onclick="printCookies();">print cookies</button><br />
    <button onclick="storeCookies();">store cookies</button><br />
    -->
    <button onclick="setCookie('smartHomePage','');location.reload();">Delete Previous Search</button>
    <div id="cachedArea">
    </div>
    <script>
        var pageScopeCookie = getCookie(cookieName);
        if(pageScopeCookie != ""){
            url = url + pageScopeCookie + "&placeholder=";
            var anchor = "<a href=" + url + ">Previous Search</a>";
            $("#cachedArea").html(anchor);
        }
    </script>



</ul>
```

Once the user enters their parameters, I display the results on a second HTML page. Code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="todolist.css" />
        <title>Search Results</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 25%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prowebapps.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sprintf.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


            function dosomething(){
                var key = "";
                var zip = getUrlVars()["zip"];
                var miles = getUrlVars()["miles"];

                if((zip == null) || (zip.length == 0)){
                    alert("missing zip code");
                    return;
                }

                if((miles == null) || (miles.length == 0)){
                    alert("missing miles");
                    return;
                }

                var api = "http://api.bestbuy.com/v1/stores(area(" + zip + ", " + miles + "))?format=json&apiKey=" + key + "&show=storeId,name, address, city";

                $.ajax({url: api, success: function(result)
                    {
                        var stores = result.stores;
                        var printStores = "<ul>";

                        for(var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++){
                            var store = stores[i];
                            var name = store.name;
                            var address = store.address;
                            var city = store.city;
                            printStores += "<li /> " + name + address + city;
                        }
                        printStores += "</ul>";
                        $("#resultDiv").html(printStores);
                    }
                });

                //$("#resultDiv").html("<h3>hey james</h3>");
            }


            /**
            obtain query string
            **/
            function getUrlVars(){
                var vars = [], hash;
                var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
                for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
                    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                    vars.push(hash[0]);
                    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                    }
                return vars;
            }   






        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Smart Homes Locator Results</h1>
        <div id="resultDiv"></div>

    <script>
        dosomething();
    </script>
    <a href="SmartHomesPage1.html">back</a>


  </body>
</html>
  <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 44.976505, lng: -93.262682},
    zoom: 10
  });
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>

        <div class="social">

            <div class="twitter">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="pauldessert">Tweet</a>
                <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
            </div>

            <div class="facebook">
                <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.seedtip.com&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=21&amp;appId=752601418144350" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>       
            </div>





    </body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine, I can call results from the Best Best API and display stores, along with a basic google map. I'm curious how hard it would be to load my json output into a Google Map, i.e. have the store locations be a hyperlink and load into google maps when clicked.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(LAT of MAP CENTER, LONG of MAP CENTER),
                            zoom: 11,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                            mapTypeControl: false,
                            streetViewControl: false,
                            disableDefaultUI: true
                        });
                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                        var marker, i;
                        for (i = 0; i < DATAOBJECT(BESTBUY STORES).length; i++) {
                            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(EACHSTORE[i].LAT, EACHSTORE[i].LONG),
                                map: map
                            });
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                                var contentString = '<div align="center"><br/>' + '<h4 align="center">' + EACHSTORE[i].NAME + '</h4><br/>' +
                                    '<h6 align="center">' + EACHSTORE[i].ADDRESS + '<h6></div>'
                                return function() {
                                    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                }
                            })(marker, i));
                        }
```

I just did that recently. You need to define the center of the map, then iterate through each data object to assign a marker to it, by its lat and long. When a user clicks the marker, they would be able to see the value of the `contentString`. I am not sure if this will work for you, but it should help with the general idea.

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a try.

Comment: Okay, just make sure to have a div, with an id="map". Let me know if it works!